# Can i get age or date of birth of users using Twitter API?

Tags: twitter

I'm working on a research and I need to get the age/date of birth of any user using Twitter API. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter doesn't store users' dates of birth so no, it's not possible.

Comment: Update: Twitter now asks for users' birthdates so this is now theoretically possible.

Comment: Although Twitter now stores users' birthdays, they still haven't opened an API to retrieve them.