# Extra field from Twitter in Rails (OAuth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, rubygems, twitter-oauth

this is my problem: I've watched many tutorials and articles about this but all of the strategies extact from twitter just a limited number of information about the user (Username, profile pic etc.), not the birth date, e-mail, genderc etc.;
just to know, is it possible to extract extra information or is it a limitation of this service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no". If you want that information you'd need to preform some sort of screen scraping.

This guy did it in PHP https://github.com/kokororin/twitter-birthday

See also: [Can i get age or date of birth of users using Twitter API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348925/can-i-get-age-or-date-of-birth-of-users-using-twitter-api)

And this: https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/twitter-connect-plugin/issues/51